# CSS target internet explorer & screen width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I am trying to add a custom style for only internet explorer but it needs to be different for different screen sizes.
To only target IE I'm using this.

```
@media screen\0, screen\9 {
    .site-logo{
        max-width: 150px;
    }
}
```

To then add a browser width I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
@media screen\0 and (min-width: 59.6875em){
    .site-logo{
        max-width: 300px;
    }
}
```

This may be easy but I cannot figure it... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property IE hacks instead

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 59.6875em) {
  .site-logo {
    color: red\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
    /* or this */
    color: red\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
    /* or this */
    color: red\9\0; /*Only works in IE9*/
    /* every browsers */
    color: red
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="site-logo">text</div>
```

Changed `min` to `max` for demo purposes